# Set cookie from Web Api 2 IAuthenticationFilter AuthenticateAsync method

Tags: c#, authentication, cookies, asp.net-web-api2

Using Web Api 2.2, I have a custom `IAuthenticationFilter` that I use for authenticating client requests with a custom scheme.

Basically, when a client is not authenticated and wants to access a protected resource, he sends an `Authorization` header: `Authorization: MyCustomScheme XXXXXXX` alongside the request. The filter then validates the credentials, authenticates the user and generates a stateless authentication token for further access (similar to a [JWT](http://jwt.io/)).

I would like to store the resulting authentication token in a cookie. When present in incoming requests, the cookie is locally validated in a separate filter (which is not presented here).

My problem is that if I try to set the cookie like this:

```
Task IAuthenticationFilter.AuthenticateAsync(HttpAuthenticationContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    if (context.Request.Headers.Authorization != null &&
        string.Equals(context.Request.Headers.Authorization.Scheme, "MyCustomScheme", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        // This works
        CustomPrincipal principal = this.ValidateCredentials(context.Request.Headers.Authorization.Parameter);
        context.Principal = principal;

        // This doesn't work: context.ActionContext.Response is null
        var cookie = new CookieHeaderValue("MySessionCookie", principal.AuthenticationToken) { Path = "/", HttpOnly = true };
        context.ActionContext.Response.Headers.AddCookies(new CookieHeaderValue[] { cookie });
    }
    return Task.FromResult(0);
}
```

Then it fails because `context.ActionContext.Response` is null. How do I add a cookie to the response from within `AuthenticateAsync`?

See related: [Setting Cookie values in HttpAuthenticationContext for IAuthenticationFilter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378822/setting-cookie-values-in-httpauthenticationcontext-for-iauthenticationfilter)
(you can see in the comments that people experience the same issue).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the filter to work by implementing `IActionFilter` in addition to `IAuthenticationFilter`. This method is valid because you get access to the request, the response and the user identity in the same place. This is my implementation:

```
async Task<HttpResponseMessage> IActionFilter.ExecuteActionFilterAsync(HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Func<Task<HttpResponseMessage>> continuation)
{
    // Process the request pipeline and get the response (this causes the action to be executed)
    HttpResponseMessage response = await continuation();

    // If the user is authenticated and the token is not present in the request cookies, then it needs to be set
    CustomPrincipal principal = actionContext.ControllerContext.RequestContext.Principal as CustomPrincipal;
    if (principal != null && !actionContext.Request.Headers.GetCookies("MySessionCookie").Any())
    {
        // Set the cookie in the response
        var cookie = new CookieHeaderValue("MySessionCookie", principal.AuthenticationToken) { Path = "/", HttpOnly = true };
        response.Headers.AddCookies(new CookieHeaderValue[] { cookie });
    }

    return response;
}
```

I find this method very unpractical (mixing interfaces), you should definitely have access to the response in `IAuthenticationFilter.AuthenticateAsync` (via an async continuation callback for exemple, or by being able to access the action result (`IHttpActionResult`) in the context, like in the `ChallengeAsync` method of the same interface).

Answer (score 2):

My requirements were to add a header but it should be easy to adapt to add a cookie.

I took a different approach on this.  I put the header I wanted to add into `context.Request.Properties`.  Then in `ChallengeAsync` (it gets called for every request regardless) via a `IHttpActionResult` I check for the presence of the property and if it exists add it to the headers.  Something like this:

```
protected class AddRenewOnAauthorizedResult : IHttpActionResult {

    public const string RenewalPropertyKey = "ETicket.RenewalKey";

    public AddRenewOnAauthorizedResult(HttpRequestMessage request, IHttpActionResult innerResult) {
        this.Request = request;
        this.InnerResult = innerResult;
    }

    public HttpRequestMessage Request { get; set; }
    public IHttpActionResult InnerResult { get; set; }

    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) {

        HttpResponseMessage response = await this.InnerResult.ExecuteAsync(cancellationToken);

        if (Request.Properties.ContainsKey(RenewalPropertyKey)) Request.response.Headers.Add("X-ETicket-Renew", Request.Properties(RenewalPropertyKey));

        Return response;

}
```

}

Then in `ChallengeAsync`:

```
public Threading.Tasks.Task ChallengeAsync(HttpAuthenticationChallengeContext context, Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{

    context.Result = new AddRenewOnAauthorizedResult(context.Request, context.Result);
    return Task.FromResult(0);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to implement IRequiresSessionState to have cookies persist?

See: http://www.strathweb.com/2012/11/adding-session-support-to-asp-net-web-api/

Comment: Not sure to understand what you mean. I do not need server session state, my cookie is a simple stateless token (like a [JWT](http://jwt.io/)), but instead of getting it from the `Authorization` header, I store it in a HttpOnly cookie.

Comment: ok, I see, I just found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22587992/jwt-and-web-api-jwtauthforwebapi-looking-for-an-example

Comment: The implementation in your link is based on a different pattern: the cient retrieves the token on a "logon" URL, then manually adds it in the `Authorization` header on each subsequent request. I want to handle the token generation on every resource (and use a cookie instead of the `Authorization` header), thus the use of `IAuthenticationFilter` (I think a `DelegatingHandler` is not really appropriate to set the user identity).